# C# - match ID to filename using functional principles

Tags: c#, functional-programming, ienumerable

I'm rewriting an old C# project from scratch trying to figure out how it can be improved with the use of functional design. So far I've stuck with a couple of principles (except where the GUI is concerned):

- Set every variable in every class as `readonly` and assign it a value only once.
- Use immutable collections
- Don't write code with side effects.

Now I'm trying to create a function which, given a folder, using yield return, enumerates a list of objects, one for each file in the given folder. Each object contains a unique ID, starting from firstAssignedID, and a filename.

Thing is, I'm not sure how to approach the problem at all. Is what I've just described even the right way of thinking about it? My code so far is a half-baked, incomplete mess. Is it possible to use a lambda here? Would that help, or is there a better way?

The `FileObject` class simply contains a `string fileName` and an `int id`, and the FileObject constructor simply and naively creates an instance given those two values.

```
    public IEnumerable<FileObject> EnumerateImagesInPath(string folderPath, int firstAssignedID)
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
        {
            yield return new FileObject(Path.GetFileName(imagePath) , );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "functional design"? I can mean different things to different people.

Comment: _" functional principles"_ - I think you mean _best practices_

Comment: I'm learning, I don't have a clear idea of what functional programming is but I've been promised it's a rewarding thing to look into.

So far, I see it as a set of constraints you put on the way you write code, which allows you to clearly define scopes and keep track of state. Functions are small and focused. You can be sure that your functions don't modify more than they seem to. A variable will only contain the one value that was assigned to it initially, so the order you put statements in is obvious - if you were to put them in the wrong order it would result in a compiler error.

Comment: The issue here is if I were to use some sort of iterator to produce an ID, that would be a variable that is used imperatively (set it to this value, now to this) and I think it's possible to do it in a simpler way with LINQ and/or lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most functional way of doing what you want is this:

```
IEnumerable<FileObject> EnumerateImagesInPath(string path, int firstAssignedID) =>
    Enumerable.Zip(
        Enumerable.Range(firstAssignedID, Int32.MaxValue),
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(path), 
        FileObject.New);
```

With a `FileObject` type defined like so:

```
public class FileObject
{
    public readonly int Id;
    public readonly string Filename;

    FileObject(int id, string fileName)
    {
        Id = id;
        Filename = fileName;
    }

    public static FileObject New(int id, string fileName) =>
        new FileObject(id, fileName);
}
```

It doesn't use `yield`, but that doesn't matter because `Enumerable.Range` and `Enumerable.Zip` do, so it's a lazy function just like your original example.

I use `Enumerable.Range` to create a lazy list of integers from `firstAssignedId` to `Int32.MaxValue`.  This is zipped together with the enumerable of files in the directory.  `FileObject.New(id. path)` is invoked as part of the zip computation.

There is no in-place state modification like the accepted answer (`firstAssignedID++`), and the whole function can be represented as an expression.

The other way of achieving your goal is to use the `fold` pattern.  It is the most common way of aggregating state in functional programming.  This is how to define it for `IEnumerable`

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static S Fold<S, T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, S state, Func<S, T, S> folder) =>
        self.Any()
            ? Fold(self.Skip(1), folder(state, self.First()), folder)
            : state;
}
```

You should be able to see that its a recursive function that runs a delegate (`folder`) on the head of the list if there is one, then uses that as new state when calling recursively calling `Fold`.  If it reaches the end of the list, then the aggregate state is returned.

You may notice that the implementation of `EnumerableExt.Fold` can blow up the stack in C# (because of a lack of tail-call optimisation).  So a better way of implementing the `Fold` function is to do so imperatively:

```
public static S Fold<S, T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, S state, Func<S, T, S> folder)
{
    foreach(var x in self)
    {
        state = folder(state, x);
    }
    return state;
}
```

There is a dual to `Fold` known as `FoldBack` (sometimes they're called 'fold left' and 'fold right').  `FoldBack` essentially aggregates from the tail of the list to the head, where `Fold` is from the head to the tail.

```
public static S FoldBack<S, T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, S state, Func<S, T, S> folder)
{
    foreach(var x in self.Reverse())  // Note the Reverse()
    {
        state = folder(state, x);
    }
    return state;
}
```

Fold is so flexible, for example you could implement `Count` for an enumerable in terms of `fold` like so:

```
int Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self) =>
    self.Fold(0, (state, item) => state + 1);
```

Or `Sum` like so:

```
int Sum<int>(this IEnumerable<int> self) =>
    self.Fold(0, (state, item) => state + item);
```

Or most of the `IEnumerable` API!

```
public static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self) =>
    self.Fold(false, (state, item) => true);

public static bool Exists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
    self.Fold(false, (state, item) => state || predicate(item));

public static bool ForAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
    self.Fold(true, (state, item) => state && predicate(item));

public static IEnumerable<R> Select<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, R> map) =>
    self.FoldBack(Enumerable.Empty<R>(), (state, item) => map(item).Cons(state));

public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
    self.FoldBack(Enumerable.Empty<T>(), (state, item) => 
        predicate(item) 
            ? item.Cons(state)
            : state);
```

It's very powerful, and allows the aggregation of state for a collection (so this allows us to do `firstAssignedId++` without an imperative in-place state modification).

Our `FileObject` example is a little more complex than `Count` or `Sum`, because we need to maintain two pieces of state: the aggregate ID and the resulting `IEnumerable<FileObject>`.  So our state is a `Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>>`

```
IEnumerable<FileObject> FoldImagesInPath(string folderPath, int firstAssignedID) =>
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
             .Fold(
                  Tuple.Create(firstAssignedID, Enumerable.Empty<FileObject>()),
                  (state, path) => Tuple.Create(state.Item1 + 1, FileObject.New(state.Item1, path).Cons(state.Item2)))
             .Item2;
```

You can make this even more declarative by providing some extension and static methods for `Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>>`:

```
public static class FileObjectsState
{
    // Creates a tuple with state ID of zero (Item1) and an empty FileObject enumerable (Item2)
    public static readonly Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>> Zero = 
        Tuple.Create(0, Enumerable.Empty<FileObject>());

    // Returns a new tuple with the ID (Item1) set to the supplied argument
    public static Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>> SetId(this Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>> self, int id) =>
        Tuple.Create(id, self.Item2);

    // Returns the important part of the result, the enumerable of FileObjects
    public static IEnumerable<FileObject> Result(this Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>> self) =>
        self.Item2;

    // Adds a new path to the aggregate state and increases the ID by one.
    public static Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>> Add(this Tuple<int, IEnumerable<FileObject>> self, string path) =>
        Tuple.Create(self.Item1 + 1, FileObject.New(self.Item1, path).Cons(self.Item2));
}
```

The extension methods capture the operations on the aggregate state and make the resulting `fold` computation very clear:

```
IEnumerable<FileObject> FoldImagesInPath(string folderPath, int firstAssignedID) =>
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
             .Fold(
                FileObjectsState.Zero.SetId(firstAssignedID),
                FileObjectsState.Add)
             .Result();
```

Obviously using `Fold` for the use-case you provided is overkill, and that's why I used `Zip` instead.  But the more general problem you were struggling with (functional aggregate state) is what `Fold` is for.

There is one more extension method I used in the example above: `Cons`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Cons<T>(this T x, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    yield return x;
    foreach(var a in xs)
    {
        yield return a;
    }
}
```

More info on [cons can be found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)

If you want to learn more about using functional technique in C#, [please check my library: language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/).  It will give you a ton of stuff that the C# BCL is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't respond in depth right now because I'm at work but I tried your first (simpler) solution last night and it worked fine. I think this way is more functional than Daniel's - one good reason is the elimination of the iterator variable but also your answer introduces functions (Range, Zip) which seem perfectly suited for the job. I didn't know you could create a non-anonymous function using the lambda operator.

Comment: Maybe using the term "more functional" is meaningless. I mean the solution conforms to my ideals better.

Comment: I know what you mean :)  Functional for me means this:

1. Use of first class functions
2. Where possible, everything is a pure expression 
3. Functions/methods are referentially transparent (no side-effects)
4. Data structures are immutable

Apart from 1, the others are optional in most functional languages. But I like to consider these best practice. You're doing the right thing trying to get your head into functional programming, it will give you super-powers as a coder. I personally wish my first 20 years as a programmer wasn't in the imperative world. Better late than never!

Answer (score 1):

Using yeild seems unnecessary:

```
    public IEnumerable<FileObject> EnumerateImagesInPath(string folderPath, int firstAssignedID)
    {
        foreach (FileObject File in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
            .Select(FileName => new FileObject(FileName, firstAssignedID++)))
        {
            yield return File;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works! I'm going to investigate it closely. A few questions though, if you don't mind, before I mark this as answered: What do you mean, using yield seems unnecessary? Is there another way of doing it? Also, is your use of the ++ operator considered a side effect or bad in any way since it's repeatedly changing the value of firstAssignedID?

Comment: Also as far as I can see, this enumerates all files in the directory and stores them in a list before yielding the first, which wasn't the intention - one by one would be more ideal. But I'll see if I can adapt your answer.

Comment: I changed my answer for your needs, still using yield seems unnecessary since EnumerateFiles is not going to do any kind of Lazy Evaluation :D

Comment: Is it not? :( Your original answer was just as valid then. Can we leave it like this though because it will generalise to other enumerators quite nicely --- unless it's doing EnumerateFiles every time we want a filename.